# Background operations when app is killed? (Android API 23+)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, background-process

To learn something new, I'm developing an Android APP (min SDK version API 23 and Target SDK Version API 28) that allows me and my family to create and share a virtual shopping list through HTTP requests and JSON responses on a free Web. Everything works fine, but I want to add a feature: I would like to get notified when someone makes a change even when the app is killed or has never been launched. I know what the task could do to compare the changes made on the list and I also know that it is something to be done once every 5 minute (for example), but I don't know how to perform background operations when the app is no longer running and it has been killed from the recent tasks list. I gave the Service class a try, but when the app is killed it stops. So I looked for a solution and I found the BroadcastReceiver and made it able to receive a message whenever the Service stops in order to restart it. But from Android API 26 the BroadcastReceiver must be (I guess..) contex-registered.

So this is what I my main Activity does when the **onCreate** method is called:

```
ReceiverCall receiver = new ReceiverCall();
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("com.dadex.familyapp.startServiceRequest"));
```

My **ReceiverCall** which extends the BroadcastReceiver Class:

```
public class ReceiverCall extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try{
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals("com.dadex.familyapp.startServiceRequest"))
                context.startService(new Intent(context, CheckListService.class));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my CheckListService **onDestroy** method:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.dadex.familyapp.startServiceRequest");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

It works fine when the app is launched, but as soon as I kill it, the receiver won't receive anything. So my question is: what is the best way to perform such background operations? Are there other classes I need to learn first? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need a background service, with a notification to keep it alive.

```
startForegorund()
```

Search for startForegorund with notification and you will find what you need.